# Перестал работать SqlDependency

Tags: c#, sql, события, sqldependency

Пару дней назад данный код работал, сейчас событие `OnChange` не вызывается при изменении таблицы. `Broker Enable`. Перечитал в интернете, подобного не было. Код брал с интернета. Может кто подсказать, в чем может быть причина? Как отладить данное событие?

P.s. в итоге понял, что при каждом создании SqlDependency, создается запись в SqlServer. И возможно, из-за большого количества копий перестает вызываться, ставится в очередь или еще что-то. Т.к. при создании новой БД, событие вызывается с добавлением записи. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Удалил все записи из `Очереди` и `Службы`, но не помогло всё равно.